# Qual modo correto de somar dois campos

Tags: php, mysql

Boa noite amigos, qual o modo correto de somar estes dois campos *valordependente* e *adesao* e exibir os valor total no input.

**Adesao = 3.500.33;

Dependentes = 90.33;

Total Correto: 3.590,66**

## Codigo

```
<?php
                     $numerocontrato = trim($_GET["numerocontrato"]);
                     $sql =" SELECT sum(cast(replace(valordependente,',','.') as decimal(18,2))) as dep, replace(adesao,',','.') as ades";
                     $sql .= " FROM cadastro_clientes where numerocontrato = $numerocontrato ";
                     $consulta = $DB->query($sql);
                     while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                          
                          $soma1 = $linha['ades'];
                          $soma2 = $linha['dep'];
                       
                          $resultadoSoma = $soma1 + $soma2;
                        
           echo "<input type='text' readonly value=" . number_format($resultadoSoma, 2, ',', ' ') . " placeholder='Total' id='total' class='form-control' name='total'><span class='error'></span>";            
                          
                     }
            ?>
```

Comment: Não compreendi muito bem a sua dúvida. O resultado não esta saindo como esperado?

Comment: O resultado ta saindo normal, o problema é que eu não estou sabendo colocar no input a soma destes dois valores. @LocalHost

Comment: O que é exibido na forma como esta agora?

Comment: R$ 93,83 nao sei porque...

Comment: Entendi, vou postar uma resposta ja

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso esta acontecendo porque esta tentando somar valores com pontuação diferente. Use desa forma, para deixa-los com a mesma formatação e depois soma-los:

```
$num1="3.500.33";
$num2 = "90.33";
//Remove qualquer pontuação existente
$num1 = str_replace(',','',str_replace('.', '', $num1));
$num2 = str_replace(',','',str_replace('.', '', $num2));

// Adiciona a pontuação correta
$num1 = substr_replace($num1, '.', strlen($num1) - 2, 0);
$num2=substr_replace($num2, '.', strlen($num2) - 2, 0);
echo $num1+$num2;
```

Edit:

```
$num1="3.500.33";
$num2 = "90.33";
//Remove qualquer pontuação existente
$num1 = str_replace(',','',str_replace('.', '', $num1));
$num2 = str_replace(',','',str_replace('.', '', $num2));
$soma=$num1+$num2;
$soma=substr_replace($soma, ',', strlen($soma) - 2, 0);
// Adiciona a pontuação correta
echo $soma = substr_replace($soma,'.', strlen($soma)-6,0);
```

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Como faço pro resultado ser R$ 3.590,66

Comment: @MauroSantos assim?

Comment: Se o valor não passar de 1 milhão, funciona kk. Caso haja possibilidade disso acontecer, é só verificar o tamanho e seguir a mesma logica,,,

Comment: Deu certo... Obrigado, não vai passar não.... rsss